# Make JGit show changes in nested repositories

Tags: java, git, jgit

Is there a way to treat changes in subrepositories like all other changes? On the command-line I would normally do something like this:

```
git add subrepo/
```

But this doesn't seem to work in JGit...

EDIT:
Here is some code that I tried. The displayStatus-method is something similar to https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowStatus.java

```
public void testSubmoduleHandling(File worktree)
{
    Repository repository = null;
    Repository subrepo = null;

    try
    {
        worktree.mkdir();

        File file;

        String filename1 = "file1";
        filename1 = TranscodeHelper.convertJavaToShell(filename1);
        file = new File(worktree, filename1);
        file.createNewFile();

        String filename2 = "file2";
        filename2 = TranscodeHelper.convertJavaToShell(filename2);
        file = new File(worktree, filename2);
        file.createNewFile();

        String subworktreename = "subrepo";
        subworktreename = TranscodeHelper.convertJavaToShell(subworktreename);
        File subworktree = new File(worktree, subworktreename);
        subworktree.mkdir();

        String subfilename1 = "subfile1";
        subfilename1 = TranscodeHelper.convertJavaToShell(subfilename1);
        File subfile1 = new File(subworktree, subfilename1);
        subfile1.createNewFile();

        repository = createNewRepoAt(worktree);
        Git git = new Git(repository);

        subrepo = createNewRepoAt(subworktree);
        Git subgit = new Git(subrepo);

        subgit.add().addFilepattern(subfilename1);
        subgit.commit().setCommitter(ich).setAuthor(ich).setMessage("Erstcommit").call();

        git.add().addFilepattern(subworktreename + "/");
        git.commit().setCommitter(ich).setAuthor(ich).setMessage("Subrepo").call();
        //          git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
        //          git.commit().setCommitter(ich).setAuthor(ich).setMessage("Full").call();

        String subfilename2 = "subfile2";
        subfilename2 = TranscodeHelper.convertJavaToShell(subfilename2);
        File subfile2 = new File(subworktree, subfilename2);
        subfile2.createNewFile();

        displayStatus(git, "Nach Erstcommits");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ctx.out().println(e.getClass().getName());
        ctx.out().println(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (repository != null) repository.close();
        if (subrepo != null) subrepo.close();
        try
        {
            //FileUtils.deleteDirectory(worktree);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'subrepositories'? Each Git repository is an independent set of content, and will be treated by git/jgit as such.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have put it wrong: Instead of sub-repositories I should have written "nested repositories".

Comment: So they are independent repositories, with independent change lists etc. If you want to see the changes in each of them, change into each of the repositories' directories and run the status commands in there instead.

Comment: I know that, but I write a gui, that watches a very big directory for changes. I want to see all changes centrally in one big timeline, so I need to see all changes regardless, if there is a nested repository or not. With the workaround above I could just ignore nested repos. I don't want to make this any more complicated than necessary.